# Нет иконки в floating action button

Tags: android

В API 21 у `floating action button` нет иконки в более новых версиях android все нормально.

Подключены:
`'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`
`'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        />
```

Drowable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:height="5dp"
    android:width="1dp"
    android:left="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="5dp"
    android:height="1dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну даже глядя на код drawable, там подключением картинки и не пахнет)

Comment: @iFr0z у меня не картинкой, а при помощи `shape` иконка сделана и подключается `android:src="@drawable/plus"`

Comment: попробуй 'android:src="@android:drawable/plus"'

Comment: @iFr0z таким способом вы обращаетесь к ресурсам, которые находятся в самом android (системным ресурсам) - человек хочет свою кнопку.